# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '28-01-2022 12:00' for column `fotostudio`.`transaction_details`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

I have gotten an error.
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '28-01-2022 12:00' for column `fotostudio`.`transaction_details`.`datetime` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `transaction_details` (`username`, `phone`, `datetime`, `transactions_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Candradimuka Production, 085328663110, 28-01-2022 12:00, 11, 2022-01-09 08:13:14, 2022-01-09 08:13:14))

Here's my Model

````
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'reservations_id', 'reservations_title', 'users_id',
        'transaction_total', 'transaction_status'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    //relasi ke galery dan reservasi
    public function details() {
        return $this->hasMany(
            TransactionDetail::class, 'transactions_id', 'id');
    }

    public function reservation() {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            Reservation::class, 'reservations_id', 'id');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'users_id', 'id');
    }

}```
````

And here's my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Transaction;
use App\Models\TransactionDetail;
use App\Models\Reservation;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function index(request $request, $id)
    {
       $item = Transaction::with(
           ['details', 'reservation', 'user'])->findOrFail($id);
       return view('pages.checkout',
           ['item' => $item]);
    }

    public function process(request $request, $id)
    {
        $reservation = Reservation::findOrFail($id);

        $transaction = Transaction::create([
            'reservations_id' => $id,
            'reservations_title' => $reservation->title,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'transaction_total' => $reservation->price,
            'transaction_status' => 'IN_CART'
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('checkout', $transaction->id);
    }

    public function remove(request $request, $detail_id)
    {
        $item = TransactionDetail::findOrFail($detail_id);
        //dd($item); 
        $transaction = Transaction::with(['details', 'reservation'])
              ->findOrFail($item->transaction_id);
              
        $item->delete();

        return redirect()->route('checkout', $item->transaction_id);
    }

    public function create(request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|string|exists:users,username',
            'phone' => 'required|string',
            'datetime' => 'required|date'
        ]);

        $data = $request->all();
        $data['transactions_id'] = $id;

        TransactionDetail::create($data);

        $transaction = Transaction::with(['reservation'])->find($id);

        return redirect()->route('checkout', $id);
    }

    public function success(request $request, $id)
    {
        $transaction = Transaction::findOrFail($id);
        $transaction->transaction_status = 'PENDING';

        $transaction->save();
        return view('pages.success');
    }
}
```

Comment: `28-01-2022 12:00` is incorrect, it should be like `28-01-2022 12:00:00`

Comment: how to change format,

I have used the format "d-m-Y h:i:s"

Comment: @ekaandreansyah You can assign it a datetime type in your model or you can explicitly set it before inserting the data into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this set format before insert data

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['transactions_id'] = $id;    
$data['datetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['datetime']));
TransactionDetail::create($data);
```